# knockout js foreach not working with child collection

Tags: knockout.js

I have a a model I'm mapping from json data that basically contains a list of categories, and within each category, is a list of controls...  So, in my UI I have a panel with a list of the categories and when the user clicks it, I'm pushing the entire category to a (at load time) empty observable to render in a another panel... the click function seems to be working but nothing is rendering in my 2nd column using the foreach statement.  Any help would be appreciated.  My json data is a bit lengthy so it may be best to refer to my fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/TU3ps/4/

But here is my how I'm trying to foreach the child, is my syntax bad here?

```
        <div class="left">Click any of the below categories to see its controls...
            <ul data-bind="foreach:  Categories">
                <li data-bind="click:  $parent.catClick"> 
                    <span data-bind="text:  Text"></span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="right">Controls within the category clicked...
            <ul data-bind="foreach:  Curr.Ranges">
                <li>
                    <span data-bind="text:  FieldName" />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Is there a better way I should be doing this?  Basically, I want my right panel to show only one collection at a time.  All I'm trying to do right now is display the fieldname but nothing is showing up.  Any help would be greatly appreciated....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if you want Curr to be an observable, not an observableArray, and you're not assigning it correctly:

```
viewModel.Curr = ko.observable();
// Inside your click method
viewModel.Curr(category);
```

You also need to add in a dummy property of Ranges, otherwise knockout blows up on the initial applyBindings:

```
viewModel.Curr = ko.observable({ Ranges: [] });
```

Comment: You mean in your fiddle, or on local code? Because your fiddle is using the mapping plugin on raw.github, which doesn't load in browsers, due to a mime-type issue (I think), so you need to use //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.3.5/knockout.mapping.js I've updated your fiddle, and it at least runs without any errors: http://jsfiddle.net/manzanotti/TU3ps/11/

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  I was also missing:  viewModel.Curr = ko.observable({ Ranges: [] }); ....

Comment: Oh, yes, forgot I had to add that to stop it blowing up on the inital bind.

Comment: I've added that into the answer now, just for completeness.

Comment: Updated your fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/sujesharukil/TU3ps/23/ based on Paul's comments.